# Rails Image Display Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, image

My application front page works fine in firefox but when I open the site in any version of IE I get an error for the top banner image, the code in the layout is this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("logo.jpg", :class => "logo"), root_url %>
```

You can see it live here: http://www.dailytrailer.net

Everything seems to be fine, when I load it in IE I always get the box with a red x in the corner.

Any idea what the problem could be here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is saved with CMYK colors. You have to change this to RGB if you want it to display properly.

Comment: exactly the problem. Thank you, had no idea about this problem till now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly what is wrong with your image file, but it doesn't have anything to do with Rails. Saving the image file to disk and opening it locally in IE results in the same 'red X'. I opened & resaved the image in GIMP and I was able to view it in IE. I suggest doing the same to correct whatever the error is and then replace the file.